# Holding an item steady against scrolling in scroll viewer in windows store app

Tags: layout, windows-runtime, scrollviewer, windows-store-apps

I want to hold a section label stable at the top of a ScrollViewer in a windows store app, while that section has not scrolled off. For example, the windows weather app does this with the section labels in the top left as you scroll to the right.

Currently the control I want to hold stable is nested inside a ScrollViewer control. I have an intermediate solution that holds it mostly steady by updating the control's render offset in response to the ViewChanged event. However, there's still some very obvious stuttering as I scroll. I've also considered "pretending" the control is in the scroll viewer, when it is actually outside of it, but this would break a lot of encapsulation.

How do I hold a section label perfectly still as the control it is logically inside of is scrolled over?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `ScrollViewer` and your Label into a Grid you can keep the label in the same position:

```
     <Grid>
         <Label/>
         <ScrollViewer>...</ScrollViewer>
     </Grid>
```

Comment: The label is inside a custom control and the custom control is placed in a stack panel in the scroll viewer. Moving the label outside of the control breaks encapsulation of concerns. I'm looking for a "nice" way.